# Как правильно протестировать клиентскую часть компонента, работающего на WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, websocket, юнит-тесты, jasmine

Существует приложение, собираемое с помощью `Grunt`. При сборке, `Grunt` с помощью `Karma` гоняет некоторое количество юнит-тестов для клиента, используя `Phantom JS`.

Сейчас возникла задача покрыть тестами новый компонент, работающий с сервером на `WebSocket`. Если с `Ajax` всё еще более менее понятно, у `Jasmine` есть описание, как его тестировать, то для вебсокетов к сожалению такого понимания нет.

Кто сталкивался с подобными задачами? Как правильно написать и запускать подобные тесты?

Upd: `WebSocket` соединение работает на чистом `JS`, без использования сторонних либ, вроде Socket.io/Nirvana

Comment: Ваш компонент оборачивает WebSocket? Что вы хотите протестировать: методы самого компонента? взаимодействие с сервером? обработчики событий? Вопрос, на мой взгляд, пока слишком общий.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov, взаимодействие с сервером. Установка соединения, получение ответа, получение соединения, закрытие соединения и т.д.

Comment: *WebSocket соединение работает на чистом JS* - это зря, сделали бы уровень абстракции - можно было бы замокать. Для тестирования непосредственно транспортных способностей вам необходимо поднять рядом тестовый сервер, который будет оббиваться запросами.

Comment: @Etki, не не, можете считать что собственный компонент его достаточно абстрагирует. В основном вопрос в том, как поднять на тестовой среде такой веб сервер на ноде, и прогнать несколько тестов.

Comment: @IonDen да вы серьезно что ли https://github.com/sitegui/nodejs-websocket

Comment: @Etki, да да, это понятно, но хочется написать автоматические тесты, которые проверят открытие/закрытие коннекта с сервером, отправку/получение сообщений на клиенте и обработку ошибок.

Comment: @IonDen так а проблема-то в чем? Пишется минимальный сервер с минимальным функционалом, поднимается в том же процессе, после отработки тестов убивается. Даже тестовый стенд не нужен.

Comment: @Etki, в том то и вопрос. Как правильно запустить, и прогнать тесты обмена данными с этим сервером на стадии сборки.

Answer (score 1):

Я честно попытался ознакомиться с жасмином, но у него настолько бедная документация, что я просто полчаса искал, как он правильно запускается.

Насколько понял, основная проблема в том, что сам код жасмина выполняется внутри удаленного браузера, поэтому из кода самих тестов сервер не поднять. В этом случае:

1. На предварительном этапе сборки поднимается простой вебсокет-сервер на тестовом стенде, который в ответ на любое сообщение плюется payload'ом в виде

   ```
   {
       "connections": 4,
       "receivedMessage": "Только что отправленное сообщение"
   }
   ```
2. Прогоняется единственный жасмин-тест, работающий на машине сборки - он проверяет, что сервер доступен (ждет, пока он будет доступен, вплоть до таймаута в Х секунд).
3. На следующем этапе прогоняются жасмин-тесты, которым с помощью переменных окружения передается адрес вебсокет-сервера, смотрящего наружу. Жасмин выполняет целых два теста - в первом он просто создает вебсокет-подключение и проверяет его на `toBeTruthy()`, во втором плюет рандомные данные в сервер и убеждается, что пришел необходимый пейлоад.
4. Прогоняется еще один жасмин-тест на стороне сборки, который убеждается в том, что к серверу подключен единственный коннект (текущий), и клиент действительно отрубился.
5. Сервер убивается.
6. Я не очень понимаю, что делают интеграционные тесты в сборщике. Сборка должна производиться без тестирования, тесты должны запускаться у любого девелопера и иметь возможность простого конфигурирования всех урлов через переменные окружения или ключи запуска. У меня, конечно, по ряду причин они тоже лежат в java-сборщике, но это отдельная сущность, конфигурация которой должна осуществляться за счет самого тестового фреймворка.
7. Никаких конкретных практик нет и не будет (особенно учитывая что по личным ощущениям в js вообще нет никаких практик и вручную пишут едва ли не больше базового функционала, чем где-либо еще), на этом уровне необходимо делать под текущие задачи, а года через два, если это будет активно пользоваться, можно будет оформить фреймворком. Если хотите делать совсем по фен-шую - тупо копируйте поведение модуля ajax.